# How to get all the element from the current template in View object in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How to get all the input element from the current template in View object in backbone.js, so that I can check the value in input element.

```
/*template*/

<script id="emptemplate" type="text/template">
<input id="name" value="{name}"/>
<input id="address" value="{address}"/>
<input id="sex" value="{sed}"/>
<footer>
   <button id="save">save</button>
</footer>
</script>

/*javascript*/

var EmployeeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  ...
  render:function(){
  ....
  },
  events:{
    "click #save": "saveData"
  },
  saveData: function (e) {
        var Data = [];
        $('input').each(function (value, key) {
            /*my problem here:
             cannot able to get the value of input element!
             */
            var v = value;
            var k = key;
        });
    }
  });
```

Comment: you want them in saveData function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update your render function to

```
render: function(){
       var template = _.template( $("#emptemplate").html(), {} );
       this.$el.html( template );
}
```

then try... 
it will add template to el of your view then you can bind and take actions on it

Comment: thanks for reply, but I 've problem in "saveData" function, I am trying to get the values of current views' element (input).

Comment: yup, when you do this in your render then you can access all input fields it will be part of your element. you can also write something like 'saveData: function (e) {
        var Data = [];
        this.$el.find('input').each(function (value, key) {
            /*my problem here:
             cannot able to get the value of input element!
             */
            var v = value;
            var k = key;
        });
    }'

Comment: or might be without changing your savedata function it retrieves your fields because it will be the part of view. if not then use .find() like the code i submit in my previous comment

Answer (score 1):

I come up with the solution, to iterate to all the input element in the current view to get the value from it. In the "saveData" event-handler when the user click the save button, like this:

```
saveData:function(){
var data=[];
this.$el.find('input').each(function(){
$input=$(this);
//build the array of [key, value]
data[$input.attr('id')] = $input.val();
}
});
```